# Generating Function Calculation Gone Wrong

Tags: power-series, rational-functions, analytic-combinatorics

Let $T$ be a function of two complex variables, analytic at the origin.  Express $T$ as a power series:

$$T(x,y)=\sum_{i,j}t_{ij}x^iy^j$$

I would like to find a generating function for the sequence $(t_{3m,2m})$.

There are standard tricks for this.  One is to write

$$U(x,y)=T(x^2,y^{1/2}/x^3)=\sum_{i,j}t_{ij} x^{2i-3j}y^{j/2}$$
and view this as a power series in $x$.  Then the constant term in
this power series is
$$U_0(y)=\sum_{2i-3j=0}t_{ij}y^{j/2}=\sum_m t_{3m,2m}y^m$$
which is exactly the sought-after generating function.

There are then standard tricks, using residues, to get an explicit form
for the function $U_0$.

But even without the residue calculus, one might hope to recover the function $U_0$
by explicitly writing down the function $U$ and then setting $x=0$.  For example, take
$$T(x,y)={(1+x)(1+y)\over1-xy(2+x+y+xy)}$$
Then
$$U(x,y)={x(1+x^2)(x^3+\sqrt{y})\over x^4-2x^3\sqrt{y}-x^5\sqrt{y}-y-x^2y}$$
Setting $x=0$ yields $U_0(x,y)=0$, which is certainly not the right generating function because there exist non-zero values of $t_{3m,2m}$. For example, $t_{3,2}=10$ and $t_{6,4}=81$.

**Question:**  What's wrong here?

I have a suspicion that the problem arises from insufficient care about exactly what rings these
functions and power series live in, but when I've tried to take such care, I've still been left baffled.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are taking a square root, the function $U(x,y)$ is not analytic at the origin. And even if it were, you are not expanding in a typical power series, but rather in a kind of Puiseux series (i.e., a power series with fractional exponents).

Comment: Thank you.  Maybe all I need to do is ponder this a little more, but I still feel like I'm missing something.  I think of $U$ as having an ordinary power series representation in $x$, with coefficients in the field ${\mathbb C}(y^{1/2})$.  So it still seems like it makes sense to set $x=0$.  But maybe what you are saying is that there's no reason to think that the power series and the function $U$ represent the same thing, at least not until you replace $y$ with a specific (and small enough) complex number.   Am I off base?

Comment: @WillO Yes, that is the idea. It sounds like you are saying, what if you consider $U$ as a function of the variables $x$ and $\sqrt{y}$? Then the square root is not a problem, but the $x^3$ in the denominator is. For example, consider $T(x,y)=e^{-xy}$. Making the substitution we get $e^{-\sqrt{y}/x}$. So even if you change variables $u=\sqrt{y}$, you are still left with a non-analytic function.

Comment: This is slowly getting clearer, but I don't understand the bit about the $x^3$ in the denominator.  The denominator contains the term $-y$, and is not divisible by any power of $x$.  So I'm still feeling like I don't completely understand the issue.  Sorry to be dense.

Comment: sorry, i meant the $x^3$ in the denominator of the transformation $y\mapsto \sqrt{y}/x^3$, not the denominator in your $U(x,y)$

Comment: Ah.  My bad. [*Added to meet minimum comment length*]